# Find 32 bit Linux Perl Libraries to run Perl Script

Tags: perl

I'm trying create a CentOS kickstart install file using [this example](http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/35-linux/129-building-a-custom-centos-6-kickstart-disc-part-2) but it requires some perl libraries.  Below is the way the article suggests installing these in my 6.4 32 bit CentOS, but the libraries are 64 bit and the command doesn't work.  What is the easiest way to install the needed 32 bit perl libraries so that I can run the below perl script?

**Librares from link:**

```
sudo rpm -Uvh \
 perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.023-119.el6.x86_64.rpm \
 perl-Compress-Zlib-2.020-119.el6.x86_64.rpm \
 perl-HTML-Parser-3.64-2.el6.x86_64.rpm \
 perl-HTML-Tagset-3.20-4.el6.noarch.rpm \
 perl-IO-Compress-Base-2.020-119.el6.x86_64.rpm \
 perl-IO-Compress-Zlib-2.020-119.el6.x86_64.rpm \
 perl-libwww-perl-5.833-2.el6.noarch.rpm \
 perl-URI-1.40-2.el6.noarch.rpm \
 perl-XML-Parser-2.36-7.el6.x86_64.rpm \
 perl-XML-Simple-2.18-6.el6.noarch.rpm
```

**Perl Script I want to Run:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::Simple;

my ($comps_file, $rpm_path, $arch) = @ARGV;

if (!-e $comps_file)
{
    print_usage ("Can't find '$comps_file'");
}
if (!-e $rpm_path)
{
    print_usage ("RPM path '$comps_file' does not exist");
}
if (!$arch)
{
    print_usage ("Architecture not specified");
}

print "reading $comps_file...\n";
print "getting RPMs from $rpm_path...\n";

$xml = new XML::Simple;
$comps = $xml->XMLin($comps_file);

%copied_packages = {};

foreach $group (@{$comps->{group}})
{
    $id = $group->{id};
    if (!($id eq 'base' || $id eq 'core'))
    {
        next;
    }

    print "#### group \@$id\n";
    $packagelist = $group->{packagelist};
    foreach $pr (@{$packagelist->{packagereq}})
    {
        if ($pr->{type} eq 'optional')
        {
            next;
        }

        $cmd = "cp $rpm_path/" . $pr->{content} . "-[0-9]*.$arch.rpm"
                . " $rpm_path/" . $pr->{content} . "-[0-9]*.noarch.rpm .";
        print "$cmd\n";
        `$cmd 2>&1`;

        $copied_packages{$pr->{content}} = 1;
    }
}

sub print_usage
{
    my ($msg) = @_;

    ($msg) && print "$msg\n\n";

    print <<__TEXT__;
parse_comps.pl comps_file rpm_path arch
    comps_file   the full path to the comps.xml file (as provided in the
                 original distro
    rpm_path     the full path to the directory of all RPMs from the distro
    arch         the target system architecture (e.g. x86_64)


__TEXT__

    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try:

> sudo yum install perl-XML-Simple

and `yum` will do the rest of the work.